# Change programmatically cell color in kable - flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, kable

Hello I have a table looking like this in flexdashboard - using the library kable.

[image]

I would like to change the color of the cells for all the future "periods".

Considering 2019-01, I want the color to change from period 15 (included) onwards; for the "2019-02" from period 14 (included) onwards... and so on.

I did it in googlesheet, and it would look like this:

[image]

Data is available on this public googlesheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12h6ztz4xRTJgwPsQ-ZkfldRYVR_dzIEg2dI5DjGdkWU/edit#gid=0)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(googlesheets)

## Import
df <- gs_title("table_values") %>%
  gs_read(ws = "Sheet1")
```

and then in markdown:

````
```{r}
df %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), font_size = 13, full_width = F)
```
````